# How to update C# User control in a Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, controls

I have a lot of instances of a user control in a C# Windows Forms Application. I found a bug in the user control and I rectified it. How do I update the user control instances in the application? Using VS 2010.

Comment: Maybe you should reopen your project?

Comment: Maybe try rebuilding the whole solution?

Comment: If rebuilding doesn't work, you can try to delete the reference for that custom control, then try to re-reference it.  I've had issues where it gets into a really weird state and won't pull in the changes i made.